# Cross-OS Intermittent Wireless Issues

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, wireless-networking, wireless-adapter

I am using a 2 year-old HP Pavilion DV6TQE that is partitioned with both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04. For a long while, I have dealt with strange wireless issues in Windows 7 that could only be resolved by either restarting the wireless card (Intel Centrino 1030-N) in device manager, or by rebooting the computer. These problems never affected my Ubuntu installation. However, I reinstalled Ubuntu a few weeks ago due to an unrelated issue, and the exact same symptoms are now present. Now as they are on separate physical partitions, this would seem to be a hardware error, if not for the fact that when running Windows 7 under "safemode with networking" my wireless works perfectly fine.

Recap:
Wireless works with Windows 7 in safemode, but not in Ubuntu 14.04 or normal Windows 7.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You know that Ubuntu is really rubbish (in fact, a lot of Linux Dist.) in accomodating WLAN capable devices? Linux developers are trying hard to get the kernel updated with all WLAN drivers. You have to do some digging to get the Ubuntu drivers working again.

Comment: @hagubear So are you suggesting that instead of a single cross-OS bug, I could be experiencing 2 different bugs with different origins and similar symptoms?

Comment: I can only say that you can expect problems getting the wireless to work on Ubuntu. I remember having Ubuntu 11 where I somehow managed to get the wireless working.When I upgraded to 12.04 LTS, wireless stopped working and I couldn't get it to work anymore. I tried lots of fixes that I found on the web; nothing was working. I guess you have to just find out why your Windows bit of things aren't working properly (which will be far easier than Ubuntu, I suppose?